# Calling Python function on a column in DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, azure-databricks

I got below function to convert string to uppercase

```
def changecase(col):
  return col.upper()
```

Trying to applying a column in dataframe throw error:

```
df['Description'] = df['Description'].apply(changecase)
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

[image]

Comment: why not just ```df['Description'].str.upper()```? no need to send to apply if you want it for only one column

Comment: function will be called on different column

Comment: tried to reproduce it myself and it works for me (expect for small intended issue on the function, guess it is copy-paste problem rather then your code)

Comment: Works for me, maybe the indentation issue is there with your code.

Comment: hmmm... not working for me though... updating question with the screen shot.

Comment: it's pyspark DataFrame :) ... think i have to register UDF and then call it on the column.

Comment: import pandas as pd
pdf = df.select("*").toPandas()
pdf['Description'] = pdf['Description'].apply(changecase)  converted pyspark df to pandas df and it works

Comment: Coooll enough. :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need `@udf` at the top of your code.

So:

```
@udf

...your code...
```